# Why is this map empty when I populate it in a Goroutine?

Tags: go, struct, reference, slice, goroutine

```
type driver struct {
    variables map[string]string
}

var Drivers []driver

func main() {

    driver := driver{
        variables: make(map[string]string),
    }
    Drivers = append(Drivers, driver)

    driver.variables = make(map[string]string) // Commenting this line makes it work, too

    done := make(chan bool) 
    go driver.populate(done)

    <-done

    fmt.Print(Drivers[0].variables)
}

func (this *driver) populate(done chan bool) {
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    this.variables["a"] = "b"
    done <- true
}
```

I expected:

```
map[a:b]
```

Actual result:

```
map[]
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TNt4uwHGAw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simple: you have a slice of `driver`s:

```
var Drivers []driver
```

Note that `Drivers` is a slice of some struct type, not a slice of pointers!

When you append something (or you assign a value to one of its elements):

```
Drivers = append(Drivers, driver)
```

That makes a copy of the value appended (or assigned)! So when you do this later:

```
driver.variables = make(map[string]string)
```

It will set a new map value to `driver.variables`, but that is distinct from the value stored in `Drivers` (more precisely at `Drivers[0]`).

**Later you populate `driver.variables`, but you print `Drivers[0].variables`. They are 2 different struct values, with 2 different map values.** Goroutines do not play a role here (they are properly synchronized so they shouldn't anyway).

Would you print `driver.variables`:

```
fmt.Print(driver.variables)
```

You would see (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UHMGFy17Lu)):

```
map[a:b]
```

If you comment out this line:

```
driver.variables = make(map[string]string) // Commenting this line makes it work, too
```

It would work, **but only because even though you have 2 struct values, they have the same map value (same map header pointing to the same map data structure).**

You can also make it work if you call `driver.populate()` on the struct value `Drivers[0]` (and sticking to printing `Drivers[0].variables`):

```
go Drivers[0].populate(done)

// ...

fmt.Print(Drivers[0].variables)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M68uheK69Z).

And you can also make it work if `Drivers` is a slice of pointers:

```
var Drivers []*driver

// ...

driver := &driver{
    variables: make(map[string]string),
}
```

Because `driver` and `Driver[0]` will be the same pointer (you will have only one struct value and one map value as the initial map is not accessible anymore). Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ge-PxwecnK).

Comment: This is the correct answer: goroutines in this case are irrelevant: https://play.golang.org/p/Eh3gPbFWPL shows the problem with only the main goroutine; understanding that struct are _copied_, but pointers (and reference types, like map) are shared is what is causing the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why using the goroutine version you are not getting an uninitialized map is that when the main function returns, the program exits: **it does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete**. Please be aware the main function itself is a goroutine.

So even if you initialize the map using:

```
driver.variables = make(map[string]string)
```

it does not mean that you actually populate with values, you are only initialize a hash map data structure and returns a map value that points to it.

> Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices, and so the
>   value of m above is nil; it doesn't point to an initialized map. A nil
>   map behaves like an empty map when reading, but attempts to write to a
>   nil map will cause a runtime panic; don't do that. To initialize a
>   map, use the built in make function.

In case you remove the `go` keyword first it will initialize the `driver.variables` map. But because it's running in the same thread (the main thread) and you put a time delay on the `populate` function first it will initialize the map, then populate it.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't the populate() goroutine run while the main goroutine does time.Sleep(1000ms)?

Comment: After Petr's suggestion I updated my question. I think your explanation doesn't apply anymore, but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Yes, it's running, but `driver.variables = make(map[string]string)` will get reinitialized if you call the `populate` function on another goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd better use channels instead of `sleep`s:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type driver struct {
    variables map[string]string
}

var Drivers []driver

func main() {
    driver := driver{
        variables: make(map[string]string),
    }
    Drivers = append(Drivers, driver)

    done := make(chan bool)
    go driver.populate(done)
    <-done // wait for goroutine to complete

    fmt.Print(Drivers[0].variables)
}

func (this *driver) populate(done chan bool) {
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    this.variables["a"] = "b"
    done <- true
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VsOzzh0MxP)

Comment: Excellent idea. Your version still shows the same problem and eliminates all doubt about race conditions. I updated my question.

Comment: @AndreKR yes, indeed, I've just noticed that it's not related to goroutines. You use a slice of structs, not a slice of pointers. It works with slice of pointers: https://play.golang.org/p/R8Vkwh_J9H